# How to Rearrange the Display of Horizontally Delineated Footnotes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, footnotes

For very brief footnotes, which happens from time to time, I would like to delineate them in a horizontal fashion.

I figured that I can do this by specifying a number of columns for the footnotes, say three, and have the footnotes appear sequentially in a horiztonal fashion; and with a new line of footnotes beginning with the fourth footnote.

The code I have used is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{bidi}
\threecolumnfootnotes

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Two words.\footnote{Column1 footnote} And more words.\footnote{Column2 footnote} And some more words.\footnote{Column3 footnote} The penultimate words.\footnote{Column1 footnote} The last words.\footnote{Column2 footnote}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this produces the output

[image]

Question: I am working on a document that starts out by listing the footnotes in a conventional manner. However, later on, there are some groups of very short footnotes that I would like to display differently. Is there a way to change the footnoting in midstream---and arrange these footnotes so that the first three appear sequentially on the first line, and the fourth and fifth (and sixth when necessary) on the second line---and so forth for a greater number of footnotes?---Also, I would like the flexibility to be able to (within the same document) to return to the conventional way of footnoting.

I have been able to do what I have shown with the *bidi* package---though it only runs with *Xelatex*. Is there a way to do what I am looking for using Pdflatex only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `footmisc` package offers a variety of footnote styles but unfortunately I don't think it can help with your particular problem, but please check it out to see if you can use it.

If you are willing to use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article`) then I think that that provides what you are after by using paragraphed footnotes instead of columnar ones.

```
% footnoteprob.tex  SE 582232

\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\plainfootnotes % the regular footnote styling
Regular footnote styling. Two words.\footnote{Column1 footnote} And more words.\footnote{Column2 footnote}
And some more words.\footnote{Column3 footnote}
The last words.\footnote{Column4 footnote}

\paragraphfootnotes
Paragraph footnote styling. Two words.\footnote{Column1 footnote} And more words.\footnote{Column2 footnote}
And some more words.\footnote{Column3 footnote}
The last words.\footnote{Column4 footnote}
\newpage
\threecolumnfootnotes
Thre column footnote styling. Two words.\footnote{Column1 footnote} And more words.\footnote{Column2 footnote}
And some more words.\footnote{Column3 footnote}
The last words.\footnote{Column4 footnote}

\newpage
\plainfootnotes
Regular footnote styling. Two words.\footnote{Column1 footnote} And more words.\footnote{Column2 footnote}
And some more words.\footnote{Column3 footnote}
The last words.\footnote{Column4 footnote}

\end{document}
```

Note that you can move between different styles, but ordering could be problematic if different styles are used on the same page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. It helps. However, when I run it in the Memoir class as you have indicated, footnotes 9, 11, 12 appear on the first line---followed by 10 directly undeneath 9. Is there a way to have 9, 10, 11 appear on the first line with 12 directly underneath 9? Many thanks.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch I have shown you the difference between `\threecolumnfootnotes` and `\paragraphfootnotes`.  As I showed you can't get what you want wirth `\threecolumnfootnotes` so (reluctantly) consider using  `\paragraphhfootnotes` instead.